# Getting local partitions on Ignite node

Tags: c++, ignite

Is there a way to get partitions of an Ignite node in C++? 
I would like to parallelize scan queries over the partitions.
Something similar to this in Java:

```
ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forDataNodes("myCache"))
            .broadcast(new IgniteCallable<Void>() {
                @IgniteInstanceResource
                private Ignite ignite0;

                @Override public Void call() throws Exception {
                   ClusterNode localNode = ignite0.cluster().localNode();
                   // get partitions
                   int[] parts = ignite0.affinity("myCache").primaryPartitions(localNode);

                   partList.parallelStream().forEach(p -> {
                        ScanQuery<Integer, Record> qry = new ScanQuery().setLocal(true).setPartition(p);

                   // query over the partition.
                   ...
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no yet Cluster API in Ignite C++, though there is some Compute API. You can track ticket [1] for updates on Cluster API.

[1] - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-5708